# How do I receive anonymized email sent to my domain?

Tags: email, dns

I have a web app in which users will contact each other using anonymized email, similar to how craigslist works.  For example, user B posts an ad and the web app includes an
anonymized address which is unique for user B such as address1U4J5K6Ldf345@mydomain.com.   User A sends an email to address1U4J5K6Ldf345@mydomain.com, and my app reads it and sends the contents of the email to user B.

My domain is at godaddy and my (django) site is hosted on the cloud on an amazon EC2 instance.  My question is how do I set up the DNS and mail servers to do this?  Do I have to run my own postfix or sendmail server on my amazon host, or is there a way to have godaddy's mail server save email to all addresses at the domain, so that I can access them by pop or imap?  Or is there some third party service that would work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use addresses of the form anon+code@domain.com where code is unique.  This is received by anon@domain.com, at least at google apps mail.  Then I can use pop to get this message with my script and can parse the to address to get the code, search the db to get the real address, and send the message.

Another possible approach is a catch-all address but that has spam problems.